# EC2 Css not loading on server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

My css and bootstrap in not loading in amazon ec2 instance working fine on local, I am using rails 7 and ruby 3.0.0 any help would be appreciated.

here is my folder structure and assets in public folder

**`ubuntu@ip-my-ip:/var/www/myproject/current/public$ ls`**
404.html  422.html  500.html  apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png  apple-touch-icon.png  assets  favicon.ico  robots.txt  system  uploads
**ubuntu@ip-my-ip:/var/www/myproject/current/public$ cd assets/**

**ubuntu@ip-my-ip:/var/www/myproject/current/public/assets$ ls**

```
Inter-italic.alternates.var-cc59cf4b324781109d703309fc7d8814b6ba74dd2822a3c029715da8cb98ea57.woff2
Inter-italic.cyrillic.var-a31159d5ce68b317b19edc7ee7f1f3ffdd5316ee899945b502406abda313afa2.woff2
Inter-italic.extra.var-cc59cf4b324781109d703309fc7d8814b6ba74dd2822a3c029715da8cb98ea57.woff2
Inter-italic.greek.var-77ec12f9397b88a29c16c05f2db87d9c0d0c2b157f1980271fed020f00b35321.woff2
Inter-italic.latin-ext.var-802705fb8496b82eda3f410c7e70a35c9407ba98b97cc5d9754db82750466fad.woff2
Inter-italic.latin.var-cbfc0334f8cfad4727431982cd32c32f7daf6e73f0ab6f759ec3dc757c1c6bf7.woff2
Inter-italic.symbols.var-59f27012284f5e97bbff303eb599ca98f29629a1c0fe7352bcc15b27d1dcd937.woff2
Inter-italic.vietnamese.var-b5dc5b6490ba49e8193315ff62c8e90551102055440f084a6e982e5eab8e589a.woff2
Inter-roman.alternates.var-29781a209d7978155bf343eb1653779269965fa4a43d504b1fb361ab20e8487b.woff2
Inter-roman.cyrillic.var-8aa524d3da3b8fd4a03ff2d0d41ea50520113fb2e8ae57c15079dabea44b3529.woff2
Inter-roman.extra.var-29781a209d7978155bf343eb1653779269965fa4a43d504b1fb361ab20e8487b.woff2
Inter-roman.greek.var-1134a39060691474b0f57b2de5e09977a31a8c06df90960b982314f58a5b4c63.woff2
Inter-roman.latin-ext.var-46bc23ba7e33ea447579cd95b95f34665d7560377065b72f3a77df8bca4b0e5c.woff2
Inter-roman.latin.var-4b87a3d384ea557b10afa9570b753eda868b12b5e51eea0977ffa6e641998f6a.woff2
Inter-roman.symbols.var-847d2a436a03ba1fbd4b750915db031a12a713befe0dcd79e8f39bf6a6e1a647.woff2
Inter-roman.vietnamese.var-a10e650090dc30250de0db440654c9bf29a843b233ee95a699b008bab0a6d498.woff2
actioncable-5433453f9b6619a9de91aaab2d7fc7ff183e5260c0107cbc9a1aa0c838d9a74e.js
actioncable-5433453f9b6619a9de91aaab2d7fc7ff183e5260c0107cbc9a1aa0c838d9a74e.js.gz
actioncable.esm-e01089c3ec4fe7817fa9abcad06cab6bdc387f95f0ca6aab4bf7ba7537f70690.js
actioncable.esm-e01089c3ec4fe7817fa9abcad06cab6bdc387f95f0ca6aab4bf7ba7537f70690.js.gz
actiontext-28c61f5197c204db043317a8f8826a87ab31495b741f854d307ca36122deefce.js
actiontext-28c61f5197c204db043317a8f8826a87ab31495b741f854d307ca36122deefce.js.gz
active_admin-3c059fb4e52fe0c526cf6057418f5f6f17a8ea6b318de112ad528015b401b3d4.css
active_admin-3c059fb4e52fe0c526cf6057418f5f6f17a8ea6b318de112ad528015b401b3d4.css.gz
active_admin-e55def3c3088e9ba3cd4c25b57ea96499e12da28eb2685ba377380f3a0b46f47.js
active_admin-e55def3c3088e9ba3cd4c25b57ea96499e12da28eb2685ba377380f3a0b46f47.js.gz
activestorage-3ab61e47dd4ee2d79db525ade1dca2ede0ea2b7371fe587e408ee37b7ade265d.js
activestorage-3ab61e47dd4ee2d79db525ade1dca2ede0ea2b7371fe587e408ee37b7ade265d.js.gz
activestorage.esm-01f58a45d77495cdfbdfcc872902a430426c4391634ec9c3da5f69fbf8418492.js
activestorage.esm-01f58a45d77495cdfbdfcc872902a430426c4391634ec9c3da5f69fbf8418492.js.gz
application-6a44a2aefa28bf0e9c530aa2f05a575ef9f89a1a916ca48e3901c5e00cefccc3.js
application-6a44a2aefa28bf0e9c530aa2f05a575ef9f89a1a916ca48e3901c5e00cefccc3.js.gz
application-dc32a83f71e964d9843a88faed276c8ea961a219fbea681d0add444f7e7d9a3d.css
application-dc32a83f71e964d9843a88faed276c8ea961a219fbea681d0add444f7e7d9a3d.css.gz
application.tailwind-b810219f330ee673842de04d3692f9c03f6ce6a19032230d1f022b3211797e19.css
application.tailwind-b810219f330ee673842de04d3692f9c03f6ce6a19032230d1f022b3211797e19.css.gz
bfg-63d1747d578ba3156fb3873f8060d98e62218ad1b82a510e1ff48f51320c2102.png
blue-a52a2a75a004fcc7dbe2f54b5e24c81f9423c151101679c91d5a49ec5578c684.png
bonfire-b4a294bd382f8e3341b87255bb196550b3ae25d4fab2edcc4ed468fb4427eb9c.png
bootstrap.min-67c48d88a8e0be178058aacb338b084191ed6d65c8fef751c50248202cf1488a.js
bootstrap.min-67c48d88a8e0be178058aacb338b084191ed6d65c8fef751c50248202cf1488a.js.gz
client-dfa62ddc9ff6e928aa8d12b188d04536494a6711f4b2be4583bddc7280cb5d33.jpg
contact_image-1c6b3e4ffe8a770d7b57895930a709e055bc269b69766e6f0511eb52af241804.jpg
controllers
cover-6c005b79409d52766ce376432d351cb688a38cf240280a5062baf2f48fa28c87.jpg
es-module-shims-69d0cb4dc1d01c9dc2ed52f2ab66874fd545fe7e35c7841009b4e8c55f231dee.js
es-module-shims-69d0cb4dc1d01c9dc2ed52f2ab66874fd545fe7e35c7841009b4e8c55f231dee.js.gz
es-module-shims.js-c69f1a5dd068dfc08a4cedc0ad77b792985bf256e162852bd03cdf764b666c4a.map
es-module-shims.js-c69f1a5dd068dfc08a4cedc0ad77b792985bf256e162852bd03cdf764b666c4a.map.gz
es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js
es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js.gz
gallery3-17da8b8356d5ac81d9e76525d41126ef2366fa9b2ce74bddfc7ce80735c461ec.jpg
inter-font-296f105e72c6ee1561ef9960d203bf7dd47cc52be2ca44b3ed3a0d4bfac7aaf8.css
inter-font-296f105e72c6ee1561ef9960d203bf7dd47cc52be2ca44b3ed3a0d4bfac7aaf8.css.gz
jquery-ui
manifest-90aab26ade71e747f745b1227b433fd7d580a54f279ee2be6e1a67bb326bf03a.js
manifest-90aab26ade71e747f745b1227b433fd7d580a54f279ee2be6e1a67bb326bf03a.js.gz
mapbg-a287abbaac3041e16208393305a0893a9ef50feaa9f43e54d56725d7ef31add2.jpg
owl.carousel.min-5965c76b27c18adb0bfa1e5def04df6fa48a2a425b426dd973a308037378325d.js
owl.carousel.min-5965c76b27c18adb0bfa1e5def04df6fa48a2a425b426dd973a308037378325d.js.gz
placeholder-9068a81cc16ca38a2e72c8aec78f7d2033a982b4ddfa4a53b3207f413bc44fa9.png
popper-25c6ab6a2fce01898eb417cf6b944e2b5e653026bbf7a0a9b989bae81acf7b54.js
popper-25c6ab6a2fce01898eb417cf6b944e2b5e653026bbf7a0a9b989bae81acf7b54.js.gz
stimulus-1bd52683afde5c8ff5572f5d49429cea5bf7744ca636fcb830c015d8cccf353e.js
stimulus-1bd52683afde5c8ff5572f5d49429cea5bf7744ca636fcb830c015d8cccf353e.js.gz
stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js
stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js.gz
stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js
stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js.gz
stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js
stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js.gz
stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js
stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js.gz
stimulus.min.js-0f3bbd3e2e72e4d7178153a52d180de4086e47082ecfc388ce82a90d8a3d7480.map
stimulus.min.js-0f3bbd3e2e72e4d7178153a52d180de4086e47082ecfc388ce82a90d8a3d7480.map.gz
trix-1563ff9c10f74e143b3ded40a8458497eaf2f87a648a5cbbfebdb7dec3447a5e.js
trix-1563ff9c10f74e143b3ded40a8458497eaf2f87a648a5cbbfebdb7dec3447a5e.js.gz
trix-b0398dade8e5ac249fe98f2e850f45adbcdfecd8a11c46b3eb67bdedb87b1b04.css
trix-b0398dade8e5ac249fe98f2e850f45adbcdfecd8a11c46b3eb67bdedb87b1b04.css.gz
turbo-4851a9a0b1d947e810dfd0448a72aef261d455183ebea681f4f28a73640a9ece.js
turbo-4851a9a0b1d947e810dfd0448a72aef261d455183ebea681f4f28a73640a9ece.js.gz
turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js
turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js.gz
turbo.min.js-8bc8f4a58d1c106d58dec8bef6c638ff12ff4d078f19d8ebd8c4277f4c9bc85a.map
turbo.min.js-8bc8f4a58d1c106d58dec8bef6c638ff12ff4d078f19d8ebd8c4277f4c9bc85a.map.gz
ubuntu@ip-my-ip:/var/www/myproject/current/public/assets$ cd controllers/
ubuntu@ip-my-ip:/var/www/myproject/current/public/assets/controllers$ ls
application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js
application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js.gz
hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js
hello_controller-549135e8e7c683a538c3d6d517339ba470fcfb79d62f738a0a089ba41851a554.js.gz
index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js
index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js.gz
```

here is my production log

```
[c17132e3-e5c0-4470-ba0a-228168e80fc6] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/owl.carousel.min.js"):
[c17132e3-e5c0-4470-ba0a-228168e80fc6]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:13:37.746321 #73570]  INFO -- : [e6bdbf18-7588-4da5-9765-dd570b2a1060] Started GET "/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:13:37 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:13:37.746658 #73570] FATAL -- : [e6bdbf18-7588-4da5-9765-dd570b2a1060]   
[e6bdbf18-7588-4da5-9765-dd570b2a1060] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"):
[e6bdbf18-7588-4da5-9765-dd570b2a1060]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:13:37.889510 #73570]  INFO -- : [6f29dc9d-bb35-4a0b-8a6b-69ff40f3a7ce] Started GET "/services/js/main.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:13:37 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:13:37.890036 #73570] FATAL -- : [6f29dc9d-bb35-4a0b-8a6b-69ff40f3a7ce]   
[6f29dc9d-bb35-4a0b-8a6b-69ff40f3a7ce] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/js/main.js"):
[6f29dc9d-bb35-4a0b-8a6b-69ff40f3a7ce]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:17.508010 #74860]  INFO -- : [81f976da-225a-468e-a20d-9a9c79119bec] Started GET "/services/new" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:17 +0000
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:17.510667 #74860]  INFO -- : [81f976da-225a-468e-a20d-9a9c79119bec] Processing by ServicesController#new as HTML
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:17.561668 #74860]  INFO -- : [81f976da-225a-468e-a20d-9a9c79119bec]   Rendered services/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 49.0ms | Allocations: 8236)
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:17.569546 #74860]  INFO -- : [81f976da-225a-468e-a20d-9a9c79119bec]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 56.9ms | Allocations: 12349)
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:17.570038 #74860]  INFO -- : [81f976da-225a-468e-a20d-9a9c79119bec] Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 58.7ms | ActiveRecord: 10.5ms | Allocations: 13291)
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.003996 #74860]  INFO -- : [b4fc52b0-b08c-44b1-b886-b2bf81816f98] Started GET "/assets/application-dc32a83f71e964d9843a88faed276c8ea961a219fbea681d0add444f7e7d9a3d.css" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.004556 #74860] FATAL -- : [b4fc52b0-b08c-44b1-b886-b2bf81816f98]   
[b4fc52b0-b08c-44b1-b886-b2bf81816f98] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-dc32a83f71e964d9843a88faed276c8ea961a219fbea681d0add444f7e7d9a3d.css"):
[b4fc52b0-b08c-44b1-b886-b2bf81816f98]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.022474 #74860]  INFO -- : [25cebe87-2443-47ee-a7c3-13cbf60372f2] Started GET "/assets/es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.023019 #74860] FATAL -- : [25cebe87-2443-47ee-a7c3-13cbf60372f2]   
[25cebe87-2443-47ee-a7c3-13cbf60372f2] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/es-module-shims.min-4ca9b3dd5e434131e3bb4b0c1d7dff3bfd4035672a5086deec6f73979a49be73.js"):
[25cebe87-2443-47ee-a7c3-13cbf60372f2]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.217244 #74860]  INFO -- : [cf0d2966-fe99-4ece-8f50-0ee4ad3eaf4e] Started GET "/assets/application-6a44a2aefa28bf0e9c530aa2f05a575ef9f89a1a916ca48e3901c5e00cefccc3.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.217728 #74860] FATAL -- : [cf0d2966-fe99-4ece-8f50-0ee4ad3eaf4e]   
[cf0d2966-fe99-4ece-8f50-0ee4ad3eaf4e] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-6a44a2aefa28bf0e9c530aa2f05a575ef9f89a1a916ca48e3901c5e00cefccc3.js"):
[cf0d2966-fe99-4ece-8f50-0ee4ad3eaf4e]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.223905 #74860]  INFO -- : [94b55d40-4502-418e-9d41-126c40493e79] Started GET "/assets/turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.224494 #74860] FATAL -- : [94b55d40-4502-418e-9d41-126c40493e79]   
[94b55d40-4502-418e-9d41-126c40493e79] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/turbo.min-f309baafa3ae5ad6ccee3e7362118b87678d792db8e8ab466c4fa284dd3a4700.js"):
[94b55d40-4502-418e-9d41-126c40493e79]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.232151 #74860]  INFO -- : [e8b634ac-8375-4bf6-b242-3cd186167d1b] Started GET "/assets/stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.232663 #74860] FATAL -- : [e8b634ac-8375-4bf6-b242-3cd186167d1b]   
[e8b634ac-8375-4bf6-b242-3cd186167d1b] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/stimulus.min-d03cf1dff41d6c5698ec2c5d6a501615a7a33754dbeef8d1edd31c928d17c652.js"):
[e8b634ac-8375-4bf6-b242-3cd186167d1b]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.238183 #74860]  INFO -- : [46078257-6a40-476f-bdea-c813f6a5e745] Started GET "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.238624 #74860] FATAL -- : [46078257-6a40-476f-bdea-c813f6a5e745]   
[46078257-6a40-476f-bdea-c813f6a5e745] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js"):
[46078257-6a40-476f-bdea-c813f6a5e745]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.243770 #74860]  INFO -- : [8cdbfb25-58be-45ca-ae27-7136618601f4] Started GET "/assets/blue-a52a2a75a004fcc7dbe2f54b5e24c81f9423c151101679c91d5a49ec5578c684.png" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.244077 #74860] FATAL -- : [8cdbfb25-58be-45ca-ae27-7136618601f4]   
[8cdbfb25-58be-45ca-ae27-7136618601f4] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/blue-a52a2a75a004fcc7dbe2f54b5e24c81f9423c151101679c91d5a49ec5578c684.png"):
[8cdbfb25-58be-45ca-ae27-7136618601f4]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.419420 #74860]  INFO -- : [985c3f1a-a23f-4f66-8c6f-88efe0e4dd7d] Started GET "/services/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.419869 #74860] FATAL -- : [985c3f1a-a23f-4f66-8c6f-88efe0e4dd7d]   
[985c3f1a-a23f-4f66-8c6f-88efe0e4dd7d] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"):
[985c3f1a-a23f-4f66-8c6f-88efe0e4dd7d]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.430973 #74860]  INFO -- : [0289fa4f-99a1-4131-b5a3-af33eb7d965d] Started GET "/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.431463 #74860] FATAL -- : [0289fa4f-99a1-4131-b5a3-af33eb7d965d]   
[0289fa4f-99a1-4131-b5a3-af33eb7d965d] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"):
[0289fa4f-99a1-4131-b5a3-af33eb7d965d]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.439828 #74860]  INFO -- : [61edbbf4-d094-4b14-8075-b99878fea424] Started GET "/services/js/main.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.440138 #74860] FATAL -- : [61edbbf4-d094-4b14-8075-b99878fea424]   
[61edbbf4-d094-4b14-8075-b99878fea424] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/services/js/main.js"):
[61edbbf4-d094-4b14-8075-b99878fea424]   
I, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.451878 #74860]  INFO -- : [2f3c67c9-a106-4009-89fd-4db5ee4054e9] Started GET "/assets/owl.carousel.min.js" for 122.168.180.138 at 2023-08-22 06:52:20 +0000
F, [2023-08-22T06:52:20.452207 #74860] FATAL -- : [2f3c67c9-a106-4009-89fd-4db5ee4054e9]   
[2f3c67c9-a106-4009-89fd-4db5ee4054e9] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/owl.carousel.min.js"):
[2f3c67c9-a106-4009-89fd-4db5ee4054e9]
```

here is my webpacker.yml

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
  GNU nano 6.2                                                       webpacker.yml                                                                
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```